# request.body is empty on posting data from react to node using axios

Tags: node.js, express, axios, body-parser

I am trying to post the data from react (front end) to nodejs server using axios api call, the url is hit and executes properly, but the the sent data is empty

**Node code***

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


let corsOptions = {
  origin: "*",
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));


  app.post("/signin",function(request,response,next){
    console.log(request);
    console.log(request.body);
    response.json({});
})



app.listen(4000, "localhost", function () {
    console.log("App is listening at port 4000");
  });
```

**React Method**

```
onSignin=function(event){

        let data = new FormData();
        data.append("signinEmail",this.state.signinEmail);

        axios({
            method:"post",
            url:"http://localhost:4000/signin",
            data:data,
            headers:{
                'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data'
            }

        }).then((res)=>{
            console.log(res);
        })
    }
```

any help is appreciated.

Comment: `formdata` is used when you want to upload a file to server. Do you need to upload a file in `/signin` API ? If not, you can send a JSON object

Comment: I actually tried sending JSON object also , but no luck......, the body was an empty object @ĐăngKhoaĐinh

Comment: You need to change the header Content-Type to `application/json` in this case. Check my answer

Comment: Thank you @ĐăngKhoaĐinh , changing the header  Content-Type helped. 
But what can be the issue with formdata?

Comment: If you use `formdata`, the server need to parse the request in another way :) If you find my answer is helpful, you can upvote or mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need to upload a file in `/signin` API, you can use `'Content-Type':'application/json'` and send a JSON object to the server.

```
onSignin=function(event){

        // data send to server
        let data = {
             signinEmail : this.state.signinEmail
        };

        axios({
            method:"post",
            url:"http://localhost:4000/signin",
            data:data,
            headers:{
                'Content-Type':'application/json'
            }

        }).then((res)=>{
            console.log(res);
        })
    }
```